# How to solve the error 64-bit requirement error invoke in play store?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I don't know how to solve the 64-bit requirement issue

already I added this line.
`ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'`

it is not unity code android app

but no use.. in playstore still shows the error message.

[image]

Comment: This link will provide answer to your question, https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit

Comment: Thank you sir.. i added **ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'** shown as above link.. but no use

Comment: Do you have any .so files in apk, which are there in 'armeabi-v7a','x86' and not there in  'arm64-v8a','x86_64' folders ?

Answer (score 1):

For this, please try following steps:

1. Analyze your app apk by clicking on **Build > Analyze Apk**
2. Then Choose the required apk.
3. Then click on **lib** folder and Check to if any '.so' files in the **arm64-v8a or x86_64** folder.
4. If it contains then app is 64-bit. No need to make any change.
5. If not, then add

> **ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'**

in defaultConfig of **build.gradle** file

Hope it works for you !!!

Comment: Thank you sir.. But in **lib** folder i don't have **arm64-v8a or x86_64** folder even if i added **ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'**

Comment: if i removed the `'armeabi-v7a','x86'` in **ndk.abiFilters** is there any issue sir?

Comment: No, there is no issue, but whole syntax works for me.

Comment: but sir.. whole syntax of **ndk.abiFilters** not worked for me.. **ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'** Only this is worked for me. successfully previewed in play store.  My doubt was is there any issue when install in mobile if i added only **ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'** this syntax.