# Is there any issue if i remove 'armeabi-v7a','x86' from ndk.abiFilters?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, google-play

Is there any issue with `ndk.abiFilters` if i removed the `'armeabi-v7a','x86'`

because if i upload the .apk file in playstore 
[How to solve the error 64-bit requirement error invoke in play store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58143338/how-to-solve-the-error-64-bit-requirement-error-invoke-in-play-store)

the above error is not coming..

whole syntax of ndk.abiFilters not worked for me.. `ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'` Only this is worked for me.

successfully previewed in play store.

My doubt was is there any issue when install in mobile if i added only

`ndk.abiFilters 'arm64-v8a','x86_64'` this syntax.

Comment: why don't you use android app bundle this will handle all the things for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a' and 'x86', then App wont work in 32 bit android devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to target all four ABIs (32-bit and 64-bit, ARM and Intel) just remove the `abiFilters` line altogether. The default is to build everything.